# Allow GRANT in procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions, sql-grant

I have created a procedure that will prepare a statement to grant permission to a user with a password. I have created this procedure to avoid having to give explicit GRANT permission to admin users, instead letting them use the procedure which does exactly what I expect them to do.

The procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE grantPermission (perm VARCHAR(30), target VARCHAR(30), id VARCHAR(8), host VARCHAR(45), passwd VARCHAR(45))
  BEGIN
    SET @setPermissionCmd = CONCAT('GRANT ', perm, ' ON ', target, ' TO ''', id, '''@''', host, ''' IDENTIFIED BY ''', passwd, ''';');
    PREPARE setPermissionStmt FROM @setPermissionCmd;
    EXECUTE setPermissionStmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE setPermissionStmt;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  END
```

When I `CALL` this procedure, I get an error code 1142 that I don't have permission to `GRANT`. There are two problems here. One, I'm executing this as `root` which should have all permissions (I have not taken any away, and `root` is the one who created the procedure). Two, having permission to execute the procedure should imply permission to do whatever is inside it.

Comment: Are you doing the call stored procedure from the command line? I created a small test and stored procedure runs smoothly.

Comment: The procedure was created by a remote client. It fails when I try to execute it either from the command line or from that same remote client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test:

```sql
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.5.35-1ubuntu1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use test;
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE `tableTest`(`id` INT UNSIGNED);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'userTest'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'userTest'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for userTest@localhost                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'userTest'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `grantPermission`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `grantPermission` (`perm` VARCHAR(30),
    ->                                     `target` VARCHAR(30),
    ->                                     `id` VARCHAR(8),
    ->                                     `host` VARCHAR(45),
    ->                                     `passwd` VARCHAR(45))
    -> BEGIN
    ->     SET @`setPermissionCmd` = CONCAT(
    ->     'GRANT ', `perm`, ' ON `', `target`, '`
     >      TO ''', `id`, '''@''', `host`, ''' 
     >     IDENTIFIED BY ''', `passwd`, ''';');
    ->     PREPARE `setPermissionStmt` FROM @`setPermissionCmd`;
    ->     EXECUTE `setPermissionStmt`;
    ->     DEALLOCATE PREPARE `setPermissionStmt`;
    ->     FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `grantPermission`('SELECT', 'tableTest', 'userTest', 'localhost', 'mypass');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'userTest'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for userTest@localhost                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'userTest'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4' |
| GRANT SELECT ON `test`.`tableTest` TO 'userTest'@'localhost'                                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So it seems like the user who creates the procedure needs to have `GRANT OPTION`. I might could use `DEFINER=`, but I'm trying to avoid MySQL-specific features for later compatibility.